# Donations over past 24 months with keys and sums

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Having pulled donations from the past two years, I'm trying to derive the sum of those donations per month, storing the keys (each month) and the values (the sum of donations for each month) in an array of hashes. I would like the keys to be numbers 1 to 24 (1 being two years ago and 24 being this month) and if there are no donations for a given month, the value would be zero for that month. How would I do this as an array of hashes in Ruby/Rails?

This is my variable with the donations already in it.

```
donations = Gift.where(:date => (Date.today - 2.years)..Date.today)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution that covered all the bases--@user1185563's solution didn't bring in months without donations and @Tilo's called the database 24 times, but I very much appreciated the ideas! I'm sure this could be done more efficiently, but I created the hash with 24 elements (key: beginning of each month, value: 0) and then iterated through the donations and added their amounts to the hash in the appropriate position.

```
def monthly_hash
  monthly_hash = {}
  date = 2.years.ago
  i = 0
  while date < Time.now do
    monthly_hash["#{date.beginning_of_month}"] = 0
    date += 1.month
    i += 1
  end
  return monthly_hash
end

@monthly_hash = monthly_hash
@donations.each do |donation|
  @monthly_hash["#{donation.date.beginning_of_month}"] += donation.amount
end
```

Answer (score 1):

the following gives you a hash, with keys '2013/09" , etc...

```
 monthly_donations = {}
 date = Time.now
 while date > 2.years.ago do 

   range = date.beginning_of_month..date.end_of_month
   monthly_donations[ "{#date.year}/#{date.month}" ] = Giftl.sum(:column, :conditions => {created_at >= range})

   date -= 30.days
 end
```

---

To select the records in that time-span, this should be enough:

```
 donations = Gift.where("date >= #{2.years.ago}")
```

you can also do this:

```
 donations = Gift.where("date >= :start_date AND date <= :end_date",
                         {start_date: 2.years.ago, end_date: Time.now} )
```

See also: 2.2.1 "Placeholder Conditions"
      http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

To sum-up a column in the database record, you can then do this:

```
 sum = Gift.sum(:column , :conditions => {created_at >= 2.years.ago})
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't communicate it well, but I don't just need the donations from the last two years--which I have--I need the sum of donations by each month for the last 24 months, with a zero value for the months where there are no donations.

Comment: how about a hash - it's a bit easier to process later

Comment: Excellent, thanks, this worked well! Had a little typo in the interpolation in monthly_donations and made date change by 1.month so as to eliminate month length variations, but other than that, it's exactly what I needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I spoke too soon. Your solution was definitely helpful--and I referenced it in my end solution--but it calls for 24 database calls, which is less efficient than I need. I came up with a solution (see my answer) that utilizes some of your concepts and @user1185563's as well.

Comment: good point. The question is how you get the records from your Donation model -- the other poster did not explain how he wants to do that.
You should use `find_each` instead of `find` , see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

Answer (score 0):

First, we need a function to find the difference in months from the current time.

```
def month_diff(date)
  (Date.current.year * 12 + Date.current.month) - (date.year * 12 + date.month)
end
```

Then we iterate through @donation, assuming that :amount is used to store the value of each donation:

```
q = {}
@donations.each do |donation|
  date = month_diff(donation.date)
  if q[date].nil?
    q[date] = donation.amount
  else
    q[date] += donation.amount
  end
end
```